# PHP syntax error when I try to write an insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, insert

So I am having the $sql variable which is supposed to be a string containing an sql insert statement.Here's the piece of code:

```
$fields = array('Nume_dep' => $params['Nume_dep'],
                'Id_manager' => $params['Id_manager']);
$id = $params['Id_manager'];
$sql = "insert into departament(Nume_dep,Id_manager) values('$params['Nume_dep']', CONVERT($id, UNSIGNED))";
```

This is the error message that I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING)

The syntax error is in the insert statement, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You should rewrite it so it doesn't have any syntax errors. Try to use prepared statements, this code as is is not safe. http://markonphp.com/mysqli-select-prepared-statements/

Comment: You're using single quotes in your SQL both around the first value, and as the key for your `$params` array. PHP is getting confused by that. As Mikel says - use a prepared statement instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id = $params['Id_manager'];
$nume_dep=$params['Nume_dep'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO departament(Nume_dep,Id_manager) values('$nume_dep', CONVERT($id, UNSIGNED))";
```

Answer (score 0):

In strings PHP will only do rather basic automatic variable expansion. The Issue is with the index operator here: `$params['Nume_dep']`

Consider to use prepared statements in order to prevent SQL injection. If an attacker can make sure, that your function is called with something like `"', 43); drop table department; --"` as value for `$params['Nume_dep']`, you're going to be in big trouble.